# Echo 'accu' from selected fields after submit

Tags: php, mysql, submit, echo

I have a database "vehicles" with tables "id" "year" "make" "model" "accu".

I got 4 dropdowns and when you press submit you get the selected values:

It is almost working but I got a problem with my last function... When the last dropdown is shown I can select all the accu's that match the year...

For example when I have 50 cars from 2013 it will show al the accu's matched to the year I selected..

How can I change the last function that it will only show the accu that matches "make", "model" and the "year"?

This is my script untill now:

```
<?php
//**************************************
//     Page load dropdown results     //
//**************************************
function getTierOne()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT make FROM vehicles ORDER BY make ASC") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['make'].'">'.$tier['make'].'</option>';
        }

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_1" ) {
drop_1($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM vehicles WHERE make='$drop_var' ORDER BY model") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Model</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['model'].'">'.$drop_2['model'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_2\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_three('result_2', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}

//**************************************
//     Second selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_2" ) {
drop_2($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_2($drop_var2)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM vehicles WHERE model='$drop_var2'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_3" id="drop_3">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Jaar</option>';

           while($drop_3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_3['year'].'">'.$drop_3['year'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_3').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_four('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}

//**************************************
//     Second selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_3" ) {
drop_3($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_3($drop_var3)
{  
    include_once('db.php');

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE year='$drop_var3'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_4" id="drop_4">
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Accu</option>';


           while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
                {
                if ($drop_4['accu'] != "") {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_4['accu'].'">'.$drop_4['accu'].'</option>';
                }
  }
    echo '</select> ';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
}

?>
```

Comment: can you please make it more clear?

Comment: Your right... its a mess.. One moment please

Comment: please edit your answer with the structure of the tables of your database ^^ or at least the `accu` table and its relation with the other ones.

Comment: @user1511766 at the time where you search for the result if you get the result with accu you can append this value with your output.

Comment: @Praveenkalal I can't get it working.. atleast I think I dont know how... Could you give me a example?

Comment: I did edit my post and what I have now is almost working, only need some help with my last function:) Somebody can help me with it?:)